# Playwright: How to search for an element that has a specific empty tag in the element tree?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, end-to-end, playwright

How to search for an element that has a specific empty tag in the element tree in Playwright tests (using their test-runner)?

I have tried an empty text filter (obviously not the best idea)

```
// variant 1
page.locator(`[aria-label="label name"].has(span:text-is(""))`);
// variant 2
page.locator(`[aria-label="label name"].has(div[role="button"] span[text=""])`);
```

but got error

```
locator.textContent: Unexpected token "" while parsing selector "[aria-label="label name"]"
```

The only solution that works for me is to check each text content using JS, for example:

```
const locator = page.locator('div[role="button"] >> span');
const elementsCount = await locator.count();
for(let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
  const spanTextContent = await locator.nth(i)?.textContent();
  return spanTextContent === '' ? locator.nth(i) : null;
}
```

Another example that gives `Unexpected token "" while parsing selector` error:

```
    locator = page.locator(`body:has(div[class="L3eUgb"] >> a >> text="About")`);
    console.log(`locator.count(): ${await locator.count()}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're mixing a little bit wrongly CSS selectors and custom Playwright's pseudo-classes.

This should work for you:

```js
page.locator('div[role="button"] >> span >> text=""')
```

**UPDATE:**

```js
page.locator(`body:has(div[class="L3eUgb"]) >> a >> text="About"`)
```

[image]

Comment: Fresh example of what is working and what is not:

Comment: The thing is that I'm looking for a parent element with empty/any mentioned text,
and for that I have to use `:has()`. 

There is a real example of a search for the parent element (body for simplicity) that contains the button "About" at `google.com`:

`
    locator = page.locator(\`body:has(div[class="L3eUgb"] >> a >> text="About")\`);
    console.log(\`locator.count(): ${await locator.count()}\`);
`
which gives me error: `
    locator.count: Unexpected token "" while parsing selector "body:has(div[class="L3eUgb"]"`

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect my exact goal, thanks!

Comment: You need to move the closing bracket earlier. I've updated the answer with the working locator.